# Dependency conflict with VueJS3 and Vuetify3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I have a VueJS 3 project with which I want to use  Vuetify 3 (^3.0.0-alpha.0), however, upon adding Vuetify I started getting dependency conflicts.
I also created a new empty VueJS 3 project with Vuetify 3 and got the same conflict.

I haven't modified `package.json` after the cli modifications on adding Vuetify 3 (https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/).

I'm aware this is an alpha release but was wondering if it was something I was doing wrong on my end or if it's a bug and if so if there are any workarounds.

[image: Output of npm update]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating all @vue/cli-service dependencies to their latest version as well as updating VuetifyJS 3 to the latest alpha solved this conflict.